# Download page first then display/animate content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, browser

Is there any way I can force a browser to wait for a page to download before showing any of its content?

I have a webpage with multiple animations on. The first time it is loaded the animations are jerky and look incredibly wrong because the content they're animating is still downloading. I need to download everything first so that the animations can then be executed smoothly. Is this possible?

The animations are CSS3 animations.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried .load() event.?

Comment: What are the animations? flash? gif?

Comment: did you try $(window).load() method ?

Comment: may be $(document).ready() will come in handy

Comment: No, the animations are CSS animations! (apologies)

Comment: Oh, so the jerky-ness is because the browser is too busy rendering your page?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Exactly

Comment: would it possibly help to delay the animations? [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp)

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Yes that is a good suggestion. I was hoping for a slightly nicer one though, something that would affect the browser's method of execution. Eg, don't display any content until the whole page has been downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

will wait for the page and external resources such as images to load, before firing.

If the animations are CSS animations, use classes or other selectors, and attach those when the window has loaded to start the animations

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.animated').addClass('start');
});
```

and in CSS

```
.animated {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.start {
   color: red;
   left: 100px;
   /* whatever you'd like to animate */
}
```

Comment: This answer is pretty spot on. I would like to add though that maybe `$(window).on('load'` is not the right time to start. You might be able to start earlier or might want to wait a while longer depending on how is much is happening. A good way to speed up the `load` event is to delay the loading of resources that are not required immediately (like things that are off the screen).

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - That is true, depending on the site, there could be many ways to do that, so it's a little to involved to add to the answer, but if images loading etc. isn't an issue, document.ready would probably be a better time to start the animations, and if there are other resources that hasn't loaded on window.onload, perhaps a load event handler on those resources would be necessary etc. This should at least give an idea of how to fire CSS animations with javascript by using different selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* here you can use some "addClass" functions. Once added they trigger your CSS animations */
});
```

Comment: Set up some classes dedicated to the animations and add them to your code in this way so they only start when everything else is loaded.